# Path to images folder in CSS in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm new to .NET and am trying to transfer some HTML into a ASPX page.  I'm building a theme and have a CSS file at the root of theme folder.  The images folder is at the root of the theme and the image I want is in that folder.  In my web.config, I specified the theme to use.  The page is pulling some of the theme, but not the images.  In the original HTML, the path to the image was:

```
url(../images/image.png)
```

I found [this article](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/278262-backgrnd-image-through-css-not-showing-in-aspnet/) that said the path should be:

```
url(images/image.png)
```

But that doesn't work either.  Can someone help?  Thanks.

The folder structure is this:

```
theme
--style.css
--images/
----image.png
```

Comment: The path to image is relative to the css, if they are in same folder, no path. You can try an absolute path for example domain.com/theme/images/image.png use /theme/images/image.png

Comment: So you're saying the path should be "images/image.png" based on the above file structure?

Comment: Normally yes, but you say that it doesn't work, you can try path relative from asp file or absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

From your CSS file, the path should be (I have tested this and it works):

```
url('images/image.png');
```

Your HTML/ASPX/Master page head section:

```
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Example CSS file:

```
body
{
    background-image: url('images/image.jpg');
}
```